# Error 3023 using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Using the Entity Framework, I've modeled a fairly simple database schema with an ever-so-slightly more complex class hierarchy.  In two places, I'm using single table inheritance with a single NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL discriminator column.  In one of those two places, it works great, no issues.  But in the other place, with an almost identical pattern, I get the following error:

Error 3023: Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 371, 375, 379, 382: Column MediaStream.MediaStreamTypeID has no default value and is not nullable. A column value is required to store entity data.
An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
  ((PK does NOT play Role 'MediaStream' in AssociationSet 'FK_MediaStream_SessionID' OR PK is NOT in 'MediaStream' EntitySet OR Entity is type [SlideLinc.Model].MediaStream) AND (PK plays Role 'MediaStream' in AssociationSet 'FK_MediaStream_SessionID' OR PK is NOT in 'MediaStream' EntitySet OR Entity is type [SlideLinc.Model].MediaStream) AND (PK plays Role 'MediaStream' in AssociationSet 'FK_MediaStream_SessionID' OR PK is in 'MediaStream' EntitySet))

Here's the table definition (not including various indexes, foreign keys, etc.):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].MediaStream(
[MediaStreamID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[SessionID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[RtmpUri] nvarchar(250) NOT NULL,
[MediaStreamTypeID] nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_MediaStream PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MediaStreamID] ASC
)
```

I'm using the MediaStreamtypeID column as the discriminator: if it's set to "video", a VideoMediaStream class should be created, and if it's set to "audio", an AudioMediaStream class should be created.

The relevant portions of the EDMX file look like this:

```
      <EntitySetMapping Name="MediaStream">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SlideLinc.Model.MediaStream)">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="MediaStream">
            <ScalarProperty Name="RtmpUri" ColumnName="RtmpUri" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="MediaStreamID" ColumnName="MediaStreamID" /></MappingFragment></EntityTypeMapping>
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SlideLinc.Model.VideoMediaStream)">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="MediaStream" >
            <ScalarProperty Name="MediaStreamID" ColumnName="MediaStreamID" />
            <Condition ColumnName="MediaStreamTypeID" Value="video" /></MappingFragment></EntityTypeMapping>
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SlideLinc.Model.AudioMediaStream)">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="MediaStream" >
            <ScalarProperty Name="MediaStreamID" ColumnName="MediaStreamID" />
            <Condition ColumnName="MediaStreamTypeID" Value="audio" /></MappingFragment></EntityTypeMapping></EntitySetMapping>
      <AssociationSetMapping Name="FK_MediaStream_SessionID" TypeName="SlideLinc.Model.FK_MediaStream_SessionID" StoreEntitySet="MediaStream">
        <EndProperty Name="MediaStream">
          <ScalarProperty Name="MediaStreamID" ColumnName="MediaStreamID" /></EndProperty>
        <EndProperty Name="Session">
          <ScalarProperty Name="SessionID" ColumnName="SessionID" /></EndProperty></AssociationSetMapping>
```

So there are multiple things about this error that I don't get:

(1) Why does exactly this same approach work for my other class hierarchy, but not this one?  I thought it might be the Entity Designer getting confused, so I deleted this portion of my hierarchy (in the XML), and recreated it, but I'm still getting it.  I could try recreating the whole damn thing, but hell, that's a lot of work, and if I'm gonna have to be doing this very often, that doesn't leave a great taste in my mouth about the entity framework.

(2) What is it complaining about in the first place?  I don't get how MediaStreamTypeID (which isn't a member of the primary key) has anything to do with the primary key at all, or why the fact that it can't be null is a problem (especially given that this same setup works elsewhere in my model!).

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the code which causes the error? I can't tell what type you're trying to create.

Comment: I get the error at design-time, i.e., just having the .edmx file open in Visual Studio causes the error.  The "lines 371, 375, 379, 382" referred to in the error are the XML lines above.

My workaround, for what it's worth, has so far been simply to abandon the attempt to use a discriminator column, and go with a simplified class hierarchy that doesn't have any inheritance.  Not ideal, but at least it was an option in this case.

Comment: OK, show the SSDL (schema mapping), then.

Comment: Sorry, Craig, I guess I wasn't clear: the SSDL that I posted above in my original question *is* the SSL that was causing the error, i.e., I was using a base class of MediaStream, which was then being subtyped into VideoMediaStream  and AudioMediaStream, depending on the value of MediaStream.MediaStreamTypeID.

For what it's worth, I eventually worked around this by dropping my idea of using inheritance to represent the different MediaStream types, and instead, I'm just using the MediaStreamTypeID column to tell the UI how to treat the underlying MediaStream object. I never did find a real fix.

Comment: And just adding to this from the perspective of several years into using the Entity Framework - I've come around to the idea that you shouldn't use EF classes to represent inheritance. If you have the choice, let your EF classes represent a simple, straightforward 1:1 mapping between the DB and the rest of your world, and map them into any more complex object models (e.g., using inheritance) yourself. I haven't needed to do it very often, and it keeps your EF classes clean.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and was able to solve it by setting the "Abstract" property for the base class to "True" and by removing the discriminator column from the base class in the model (either in the *.edmx file or in the designer view within Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1):

I got the exactly same error but maybe with different reason from yours.
In the code below, I mis-copied some codes so 2 of inherited classes (LeveledItem  and Team) are of the same "Type".

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new ScrumDbContextInitializer());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<LeveledItem>()
            .Map<LeveledItem>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(typeof(LeveledItem).Name))
            .Map<Team>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(typeof(LeveledItem).Name))
            .Map<Story>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(typeof(Story).Name))
            .Map<Task>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(typeof(Task).Name))                 .Map<Sprint>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(typeof(Sprint).Name));
```

After the second one was changed to "typof(Team).Name", the error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this, just out of interest, does deleting the .EDMX file and recreating it from scratch solve your problem?

What caused the problem:

1. Created a set of tables with some 0..* mappings
2. Generated the Entity Framework class, customised a whole bunch of Navigation properties
3. Went back to the DB and changed the cardinality of some of the 0..* to 1..* relationships - ie: set some of the FKs to !nullable
4. Updated the Entity Framework
5. Recompiled and *BOOM* I got a compilation error similar to yours

There seems to be an issue where the "Update Model from Database" command doesn't update the changed relationships correctly.

The solution was to open the EDMX file, look for the `<Association Name="FK_XXX_XXX">` elements that were generated the first time and change the Multiplicity attribute on the relevant End point from `Multiplicity="0..1"` to `Multiplicity="1"`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I inadvertently mapped 2 classes to the same table via the [Table] attribute (same effect via modelBuilder ToTable())